# Shadow distance decreases in mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, render, shadow

In the Unity editor, shadow distance is very good and I can see every shadow. However when I build the game to mobile shadow distance decreases for some reason.

I tried to make the shadow distance long but it didn't worked, it is still the same in mobile.

-I didn't do anything in the game I only put capsules in it. I don't understand why this isn't working.[image: Unity Editor :]
[image: Mobile(Android)]

Comment: surely this is down to the quality its able to process

Comment: I want to know which device is used to execute game that is mobile version. Many developers used simulation program for developing...

Comment: I tested it in 4-5 android devices and all of them doesn't able to get the far shadows. I don't think it is about quality it is able to process because I tested it on new and old devices. Have you got any solution? I need that really.

Comment: Increasing the Shadow Distance should definitely solve the problem in your case. Is it possible that you forgot to select the correct ```Quality Level``` before increasing the shadow distance? You can select the Quality Level in the table that is displayed at the top of the Quality Settings by clicking on the row with a green check mark in the mobile column (if you build for android, it is the column with the android symbol). You will see that you have selected the correct row if the entry a little further down at ```Name``` has changed to the corresponding level name.

Comment: **Fixed it.**
Somehow, I upgraded my target api level to 33 and it is gone. Thanks for everyone who helped me.